# Tests on CI server are failing (Xcode 9) iOS

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, xctest, xcuitest

Trying to setup continuous integration for my iOS app. Wrote bunch of unit tests that run fine locally for both phone and simulator.

However, when I run my CI bots the tests are failing with this error:

" Test target X encountered an error (Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted) "

There is no more explanation to be found in the logs or anything like that. The bot is set up to use only iPhone 7 iOS 11.2 simulator.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

EDIT: I partially fixed this issue by changing Runpath Search Paths on my Test target in Build Settings to $(FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS).

However, I still get this error if I use more than one simulator on the bot :( So if I use only one simulator everything works fine, but if I use more than one it would fail for all of them or at least for one of them with this same error...

Comment: What CI provider are you using? It's likely that you need to upload the correct certificates for the bot to run your app.

Comment: the certs and the profiles are correct, I use native Mac Server and xcode

Comment: Are you running parallel tests, by any chance?

Comment: should be sequential...unless UI and Unit tests run in parallel by default ?!